# How to convert an executable excel file to binary (exe to xlsb) with PowerShell?

Tags: excel, powershell, executable, xlsb

I'm trying to get data from an executable excel file (which is an excel file compressed and wrapped into an .exe) without success using PowerShell. I can open it, but I can't get the values stored in it.

I've been able to get data from binary excel files though (.xlsb).

```
$FilePath = "d:\database\temp.xlsb"
$SheetName = "NDC"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$WorkSheet = $Workbook.sheets.item($SheetName)
$value = $Worksheet.Range("A1").Text
```

Then, my question is, is it possible to open the excel exe file and save the file with a format that can be accessed with PowerShell?

Comment: Which method/program did you use to turn the Excel file into an executable?

Comment: @BoogaRoo I will check if I can get that information. Anyway, can it influence the way you turn it back to a conventional Excel file?

Comment: Probably. Unless it is just a straight zip-to-exe pack of the file, I am guessing it was something like DoneEx XCell or something similar. If they did use "copy protection" options with the converter it may not be feasible to recover. Hard to say without knowing more, though if you are able to open them they're probably not protected(or you know the password).

Comment: @BoogaRoo There is protection with password when opened for the first time. Once you write the correct password, a text file with a code is created in the folder of the file, so there's no need to enter the password again. Not sure if it helps. Anyway I'll check in the office if anyone knows about the method used.

Comment: @BoogaRoo The excel file has been compressed and wrapped in an executable.